# ISQL 7.3 (SuSE): Ace report output to more than one file or stdout

Tags: informix

Does anyone know how I could trick Ace into outputing to more than one file or to a file and display simultaneously without having to write an external script?.. i.e. in the Ace spec OUTPUT REPORT TO PIPE or OUTPUT REPORT TO "filename.out" > /dev/tty01a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For piping to multiple files, you can use:

```
OUTPUT
    REPORT TO PIPE "tee file2 >file1"
```

You can do more than two files if you want to, courtesy of the abilities of the `tee` program.  Clearly, if you want the output to go to standard output as well as to a file, you pipe it to `tee` without the '`>`' redirection.

You can get the output to a pager if you use:

```
OUTPUT
    REPORT TO PIPE "tee file1 file2 | less"
```